# How to do pip installation from git without removing the source folder?

Tags: python, git, pip

If I do `pip install git+https://github.com/clab/dynet#egg=dynet` then it will:

- clone the repository source to a folder, for example: `/private/var/folders/rk/somefolder/T/pip-build-yZIKna/dynet`
- do the compilation there, and then
- remove the cloned folder

How to prevent the removal of the source folder or restore it?

**EDIT:**
Unfortunately, `--no-clean` [is broken](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3171), I just tried it. Still seeing this in verbose mode:

```
Removing source in 
/private/var/folders/rk/somefolder/T/pip-build-LRuDhC/dynet
```

Comment: `--no-clean` as an argument leaves the build directory around.

Answer (score 1):

The `--no-clean` flag should do the trick:

```
$ pip install --no-clean git+https://github.com/clab/dynet#egg=dynet
```